# Terraform resources not getting destryoed from terminal

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, helm, eks

I wanted to destroy the `DEV` environment from my Kubernetes hosted on AWS EKS. There are two parts to the resources; the infrastructure part and the application part. I use `Terraform`/`Terragrunt` to deploy/destroy the infra and `helm` to deploy/destroy the applications. There are multiple pods running and I could destroy the releases by running `helm uninstall <release-name>`. However, when it came to destroying the infra, I ran into error.
Here is what I did:

To destroy the infra, I ran: `ENV=DEV make destroy`. To this command, it returns this:

`cd infra/DEV && terragrunt destroy`

```
Remote state S3 bucket aib-iac-tf-state does not exist or you don't have permissions to access it. Would you like Terragrunt to create it? (y/n)
```

To this, I tried with both `y` and `n` but it returns this error:

```
make: *** [Makefile:30: destroy] Error 1
```

Assuming that my access was altered by the root user to create/delete resources inside `S3 Bucket`, I found it was not. The `S3 Bucket` `aib-iac-tf-state` does exist in the storage.

Then I went to check inside `*Makefile*`, line 30 as per the error. This is what is in line 29 and 30:

```
destroy:
    cd ${INFRA_DIR}/${ENV} && terragrunt destroy ${TF_VARS}
```

I am still not able to destroy the resources. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error from Terraform is telling you that it's remote state bucket does not exist, and therefore it can't read the remote state to understand what to destroy. This sounds like a misconfiguration in the wrapper that you're using via Make.

If you can, check the `.tf` files for a block like this:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "mybucket"
    key    = "path/to/my/key"
    region = "us-east-1"
  }
}
```

And make sure that the bucket has the correct name. You may need to compare with your AWS account to find a bucket that holds the right data.

If you can't find anything like that - check in your local workspace for a `.tfstate` file, and then remove the `backend` block so it's using your local state file not a remote backend. **YMMV** - you may want to find a colleague with Terraform skills and get them to take a look!

TL;DR - sounds a bit like a bug in the wrapper to me, or something has got deleted out of order.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. I could locate a file with `.hcl` extension called `remote.hcl`. 
`remote_state {
  backend = "s3"
  generate = {
    path      = "backend.tf"
    if_exists = "overwrite_terragrunt"
  }
  config = {
    profile        = "${yamldecode(file("${get_terragrunt_dir()}/vars.yml")).inputs.profile}"
    bucket         = "aib-iac-tf-state"
    key            = "${path_relative_to_include()}/terraform.tfstate"
    region         = "us-east-1"
    encrypt        = true
    dynamodb_table = "aib-iac-tf-state-lock"
  }
}`
Any guidance would be thankful.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. I could not upvote your answer due to insufficient reputation but I could solve it following your guidance.